# Floating week time schedule

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm currently developing an application that calculates prices depending on the day and time of the day. So in my database I have something like:

```
day_of_week | start_time | end_time
```

The services that we are charging have a duration. So if I have a transaction with a start_datetime and end_datetime.

To be able to do the comparison I have to transpose either the floating time or the actual datetime.

This is start to become a bit cumbersome when you have to deal with transaction that overlap two days or two weeks. And also the fact that it seems that for SQL an interval from 23:00 to 24:00 is interpreted as midnight of the next day.

This seems to be a very common issue so I'm thinking that there is a better way to approach the problem. While joda-time helps a lot, I don't seem to find something for this particular problem.

It would really help if you can share how you deal with this problem.

Thanks,
Mauricio

Comment: So what is your real question? Is it the 24:00/0.00 issue or what?

Comment: Why store the day of week in addition to start and end times? Why not just store two full fledged timestamps?

Comment: Because I don't want them to be linked to a specific date. It is every monday from 12:00 to 15:00 use this price, every monday from 15:00 to 18:00 use this other, etc...

Comment: Btw, I'm open to any suggestions, changing the database structure could be one of them.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno The question is how to deal with this problem in a better way. As the way that I'm doing it right now, makes for a very verbose code with special cases.